# Unable to send telegram message using pyrogram and flask

Tags: python, flask, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I am using this code to connect to telegram api , and send message on telegram , there is a flask app running , which has an endpoint /listen , which should send a message on telegram .
But i am unable to send the message
Below is the code .

To recreate you will need:

1. Api id
2. Api hash

You can get this from https://my.telegram.org/auth

Below is my code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pyrogram import Client, filters

# Replace 'YOUR_API_ID' and 'YOUR_API_HASH' with your actual API credentials
API_ID = 'YOUR_API_ID'
API_HASH = 'YOUR_API_HASH'

# Create a Pyrogram client
app = Client("my_bot", api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

# Create a Flask web application
flask_app = Flask(__name__)

# Define a route for the '/listen' endpoint
@flask_app.route('/listen', methods=['POST'])
def listen():
    # Get the JSON data from the incoming message
    data = request.get_json()

    # Check if the message contains a 'command' key with the value 'send_message'
    if 'command' in data and data['command'] == 'send_message':
        # Extract the 'message' field from the incoming data
        message_text = data.get('message')

        # Replace 'me' with your own Telegram username or recipient chat ID
        recipient = 'me'

        # Send the message to the recipient
        app.send_message(recipient, message_text)

        return "Message sent successfully!"

    return "Command not recognized."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the Flask server
    flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

After I hit the /listen endpoint I get this error

```
Task <Task pending name='Task-46' coro=<AsyncToSync.main_wrap() attached to a different loop
```

This error occures at
`await app.send_message(recipient, 'hi')`

What should be the issue ?

Comment: you cannot execute asynchronous code in synchronous code.

Comment: @SinanCetinkaya can you share a solution for this ?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/async-await/